# Why is "Render Flow in Lightning Runtime" disabled?

Tags: visual-workflow

Please refer to the screenshot below. Why is the Render Flow in Lightning Runtime always disabled?

I could work around it by editing the element from developer tools on the browser and save it with a check. But, I would like to understand why it's not enabled.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_login_flow_associate.htm&type=5), It is not suggestable to enable 'Render Flow in Lightning Runtime' due to security risk of unauthorized access

[image]

Also, If this setting is enabled login flow shows "Flow is Finished" before redirecting. Kindly check bug details [here](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000019QNhQAM&title=login-flow-shows-flow-is-finished-before-redirecting-when-render-flow-in-lightning-runtime-is-enabled)  which has no fix.